# Is there a utility like `watch` except event triggered?

Tags: linux

`watch` is great for monitoring events on a polling basis. However I'm looking for a utility that's similar, except event-driven (i.e. monitoring every change to a file in /sys/kernel/debug/my_node).  Is there already such a utility?

Comment: monitoring saved changes can be done with `inotify`.

Comment: I saw that.  That's a raw C API right?  Is there CLI utility that works has a handy wrapper around it? Edit: I just RTFMed and found this: https://github.com/rvoicilas/inotify-tools/wiki

Comment: @R.d. there are also commands that uses `inotify` APIs with names starting with `inotify`.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/rvoicilas/inotify-tools

example usage: `inotifywait -e modify -m /tmp/foo &; echo test > foo`

prints: `/tmp/foo MODIFY`

Comment: Not in `/sys`. Files in `/sys` don't exactly change, because their content is generated on the fly. They just happen to have a different value the next time you read them. In general the only way to detect a change to a file in `/sys` is by polling.

Answer (score 0):

Use `tail -f /sys/...` to follow the last bit of a file, and any new output